# Search documents using $gt filter with go-mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime, go, filter

I'm stuck at a probably simple problem: If I filter this in mongodb compass (filter `{dateTime:{$gt: new Date("2020-11-23T12:31:38")}}`):
It returns 556 documents.

Trying to create a cursor in Go that have those documents is proving to be quite hard!
I've this right now:

```
cursor, err := coll.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{"dateTime": bson.M{"$gt": "new Date("+ date + ")"}}, opt)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Err creting database: ", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    if cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        fmt.Println("Cursor0!")
        cursor.Next(context.Background())
    }
    cursor1, err := coll.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{}, opt)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Err creting database: ", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    if cursor1.Next(context.Background()) {
        fmt.Println("Cursor1!")
        cursor.Next(context.Background())
    }.
```

I've tried, along other different tries, to put the filter just as `bson.M{"dateTime": bson.M{"$gt": date}}`, along other similar tryes, but they also returned 0 documents. The `date` variable have exacly the date used in the mongodb compass filter.

I created another cursor, with no filter, just to control if the connection with mongo is ok, and to see if it returns any documents when it has no filter, and it does return documents. Does anyone knows the answer to this one?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question); copy/paste the text and [format it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was dealling with more than 1 Collection, and in one the date was saved as string, and in the other, as date. In the one that the date s saved as string, no surprise, we have to send the date as string too, some logic to when date is in mongo as Date

Answer (score 0):

`new Date("2020-11-23T12:31:38")` is JavaScript syntax. You need to use the proper Go syntax for creating timestamps.